# Run Time error while iterating over a vector

Tags: c++

I am Iterating over a vector that stores Point data type elements [x,y], And what i want to achieve at every iteration is to add first 4 point x elements and first 4 points y elements....The during the next iteration i want to do the same with the next 4 x & y......and so on

1st iteration  1.x + 2.x + 3.x + 4.x
               1.y + 2.y + 3.y + 4.y

2nd iteration  5.x + 6.x + 7.x + 8.x
               5.y + 6.y + 7.y + 8.y

and so on.....................Hope my problem is clear

Sample code:

```
double Pta; 
    double Ptb;
    Point  vect;
    float R1, R2;
    float resultant;
    vector<Point> vect_add;
    for(vector<Point>::iterator iter_a = Left_Arm_xy.begin()+1; iter_a != Left_Arm_xy.end(); ++iter_a)
    {

        if(center.y <= 240)
        {
            vect.x = iter_a->x - (iter_a -1)->x;
            vect.y = iter_a->y - (iter_a -1)->y;

            vect_add.push_back(Point(vect.x,vect.y));


            for(vector<Point>::iterator iter_v = vect_add.begin(); iter_v != vect_add.end(); ++iter_v)
            {



                    R1 = iter_v->x + (iter_v +1)->x + (iter_v +2)->x + (iter_v +3)->x;
                    R2 = iter_v->y + (iter_v +1)->y + (iter_v +2)->y + (iter_v +3)->y;

                    resultant = sqrt(pow(R1,2) + pow(R2,2));



                    cout<<"Resultant: "" "<<resultant<<endl;

            }

        }
```

When i comet out the part where I am trying to add all the x's and y's the program works fine just like it did before.....Therefore the issue must me there..I guess the syntax is not right but am not the best programmer and couldn't this of whats wrong as there is no compiler warnings....the program just crashes at run time

Can anyone possibly see what I am doing wrong with this code
regards

Debug:
[image]

Sorry for just adding the photo of the Debug breakpoint but i think picture is worth 1000 words in this case :P

Comment: What do you suspect `vect_add.size() >4` means?

Comment: if there are more than 4 elements inside this vector then proceed and execute the code this within this if statement

Comment: You are correct.  So if `vect_add.size()` is 3, that code is never run.  And if `vect_add.size()` is 5, it will be run 5 times.  That doesn't match your description of the program.

Comment: Thx for your suggestion the reason why my code might not be corresponding to my question is because the code its self is not 100% correct this is why i am looking for some kind of help :P

Comment: You're almost there now.  Considering that you want to look at these elements in **4 at a time**, re-examine the `++iter_v` in your `for` loop.  `++iter_v` means "1 at a time".

Comment: Ok i also tried this before with all the excess code therefore i tried again with what has been suggested `iter_v+4` and still out of luck :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by controlling whether your iterator + 3 exceeds you vector (vect_add) limits so that you won't exceed vector bounds, also for each iteration you have to increase iterator by 4 to obtain your designed scheme:

```
for(vector<Point>::iterator iter_v = vect_add.begin(); iter_v - vect_add.begin() + 4 < vect_add.size(); iter_v+=4)
{ 
       R1 = iter_v->x + (iter_v +1)->x + (iter_v +2)->x + (iter_v +3)->x;
       R2 = iter_v->y + (iter_v +1)->y + (iter_v +2)->y + (iter_v +3)->y;

       resultant = sqrt(pow(R1,2) + pow(R2,2));



       cout<<"Resultant: "" "<<resultant<<endl;

 }
```

Here, iter_v - vect_add.begin() gives the index of current iterator and in the for loop we check whether there is a sufficient number of elements for your addition operation.

Comment: hehe you the man :) thank you very much not at any point i was close to this solution. Regards

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems is here:

```
R1 = iter_v->x + (iter_v +1)->x + (iter_v +2)->x + (iter_v +3)->x;
R2 = iter_v->y + (iter_v +1)->y + (iter_v +2)->y + (iter_v +3)->y;
```

`iter_v + 1` to `iter_v+ 3` may be out of range, resulting in trying to access memory that does not belong to the `vector`, therefore, crash.

The check condition `if(vect_add.size() >4)` does not help much in this case.

This piece does not make sense at all:

```
if(vect_add.size() > 20)
{
    vect_add.clear(); //does not make sense, you remove all the elements in vector?
}
```

Comment: thank for your reply....ye i though this would be the problem thats why i added this condition `if(vect_add.size() >4)` so how could i rearrange change this so that i can achieve what am after...?

Comment: @Tomazi you may change your vector iteration condition to : iter_v +3 != vect_add.end(). The check is not useful in this case at all.

Comment: ok i removed the check and tired your suggestion bu increasing my iter_v+3 on every iteration and the effect is the same..

Comment: @Tomazi my suggestion is that you try to set break points in your code and use a debugger to step into them to see what exactly happened.

Comment: Ok i have gone throught Debug and discovered that well i think that what it means....x and y is missing at some point during the iteration.....Uploaded the photo in my original post above ^^^^^

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is related but clearing vectors invalidates iterators.  From [std::vector clear](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/clear/)

> All iterators, pointers and references related to this container are invalidated.

You clear your vector here

```
if(vect_add.size() > 20)
{
     vect_add.clear();
}
```

Comment: yes you are right the reason why i have this if statement is because i was trying something :P and forgotten to remove this part while creating this post...